# ASP.NET WebAPI Help Pages Additional Information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have written a WebAPI service, however, I want to show sample of the information that should be included in the route values. I thought I would show this information in the Additional Information section.

How do I go about this? Note: I am using the default Help Page.